# Downhill Maze Solver

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, path-finding, grid

A downhill maze is given as a series of rows of space separated digits from 0 to 9 inclusive, plus one "S" and one "X", where the S denotes the start and the X denotes the finish.  In a downhill maze, you may only go to a space that is adjacent to you to the north, south, east, or west (no diagonals), and you may only go to spaces with a value less than or equal to the value you are currently on.

The program should output a path to navigate through the maze in the same format as the input, only all traversed spaces should have a "." in them, and all unvisited spaces should have a "#" in them.  The starting and ending cells should also keep their "S" and "X", respectively.  You can assume there is always a solution to the maze.

Example input:

```
3 3 3 3 2 1 S 8 9
3 1 1 3 3 0 6 8 7
1 2 2 4 3 2 5 9 7
1 2 1 5 4 3 4 4 6
1 1 X 6 4 4 5 5 5
```

Example output:

```
. . . . # # S . #
. # # . . # # . .
. # # # . # # # .
. # # # . # # # .
. . X # . . . . .
```

Comment: Can you move to and from `S` and `X` in any direction? Is the maze always solvable?

Comment: Also, can we assume that all the rows have the same length? And, just to clarify, a "digit" means a *single* decimal digit from `0` to `9` inclusive, right?

Comment: @Calvin Yes, you you may move to and from S and X in any direction.  The maze is assumed to be solvable.

Comment: @IImari Yes, all rows have the same length, and yes, a "digit" is a single digit from 0 to 9 inclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6) 219

A function returning true or false. The solution (if found) is output on the console.
It does not try to find an optimal solution.

```js
f=o=>(r=(m,p,w=0,v=m[p])=>
v>':'
  ?console.log(' '+m.map(v=>v<0?'#':v,m[f]='X').join(' '))
  :v<=w&&[1,-1,y,-y].some(d=>r([...m],d+p,v),m[p]='.')
)(o.match(/[^ ]/g).map((v,p)=>v>'S'?(f=p,0):v>':'?v:v<'0'?(y=y||~p,v):~v,y=0),f)
```

**Ungolfed** to death and explained more than needed

```js
f=o=>{
  var r = ( // recursive search function
    m, // maze array (copy of)
    p, // current position
    w  // value at previous position
  )=> 
  {
    var v = m[p]; // get value at current position
    if (v == 'S') // if 'S', solution found, output and return true
    {
      m[f] = 'X'; // put again 'X' at finish position
      m = m.map(v => { // scan array to obtain '#'
        if (v < 0) // a numeric value not touched during search
          return '#'
        else  
          return v  
      }).join(' '); // array to string again, with added blanks (maybe too many)
      console.log(' '+m) // to balance ' '
      return true; // return false will continue the search and find all possible solutions
    }
    if (v <= w) // search go on if current value <= previous (if numeric, they both are negative)
    {
      m[p]='.'; // mark current position 
      return [1,-1,y,-y].some(d=>r([...m], d+p, v)) // scan in all directions
    }
    // no more paths, return false and backtrack
    return false
  }

  var f, // finish position (but it is the start of the search)
      y = 0; // offset to next/prev row
  o = o.match(/[^ ]/g) // string to char array, removing ' 's
  .map((v,p) => // array scan to find f and y, and transform numeric chars to numbers 
   {  
     if (v > 'S') // check if 'X'
     {
       f = p;
       return 0; // 'X' position mapped to min value
     }
     if (v > ':') // check if 'S'
       return v; // no change
     if (v < '0') // check if newline
     {
       if (!y) y = ~p; // position of first newline used to find y offset
       return v; // no change
     }
     return ~v; // map numeric v to -v-1 so have range (-1..-10)
   })

  return r(o, f, 0) // start with a fake prev value
}
```

**Test** in Firefox/FireBug console

```
f('3 3 3 3 2 1 S 8 9\n3 1 1 3 3 0 6 8 7\n1 2 2 4 3 2 5 9 7\n1 2 1 5 4 3 4 4 6\n1 1 X 6 4 4 5 5 5')
```

*Output*

```
. . . . # # S . #   
. # # . . # # . .   
. # # # . # # # .   
. # # # . # # # .   
. . X # . . . . .  

true
```

Comment: We seem to share a mutual code unfathomability.

Comment: @Sieg why, isn't it crystal clear? I'll add an explanation tomorrow

Comment: @Sieg more fathomable?

Comment: Fathomable indeed.

Answer (score 4):

## C# - 463

Accepts input via STDIN, and should produce an optimal path, tested for the given test case, but not otherwise. Assumes there is always a solution.

I'm in a bit of a hurry, I have a deadline in 7 hours, but this just looked like too much fun to miss out on. I'm also out of practice. It could be very embarrassing if this goes wrong, but it's reasonably golfed.

```c#
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){var S=C.In.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r","").Replace('X','+');int s=S.IndexOf('S'),e=S.IndexOf('+'),w=S.IndexOf('\n')+1,L=S.Length,i,j=L;var K=new int[L];for(K[s]=s+2;j-->0;)for(i=0;i<L;i+=2){System.Action<int>M=z=>{if((z+=i)>=0&z<L&&S[z]<=S[i]&K[z]<1&K[i]>0&(i%w==z%w|i/w==z/w))K[z]=i+1;};M(2);M(-2);M(w);M(-w);}for(w=e;w!=s+1;w=i){i=K[w]-1;K[w]=-1;}for(;++j<L;)C.Write(j%2<1?K[j]<0?j==s?'S':j==e?'X':'.':'#':S[j]);}}
```

Code with comments:

```c#
using C=System.Console;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var S=C.In.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r","").Replace('X','+'); // read in the map, replace X with + because + < 0
        int s=S.IndexOf('S'),e=S.IndexOf('+'),w=S.IndexOf('\n')+1,L=S.Length,i,j=L; // find start, end, width, length

        var K=new int[L]; // this stores how we got to each point as loc+1 (0 means we havn't visited it)

        for(K[s]=s+2; // can't risk this being 0
            j-->0;) // do L passes
            for(i=0;i<L;i+=2) // each pass, look at every location
            {
                // if a whole load of bouds checks, point new location (i+z) at i
                System.Action<int>M=z=>{if((z+=i)>=0&z<L&&S[z]<=S[i]&K[z]<1&K[i]>0&(i%w==z%w|i/w==z/w))K[z]=i+1;};
                // try and move in each direction
                M(2);
                M(-2);
                M(w);
                M(-w);
            }

        for(w=e;w!=s+1;w=i) // find route back
        {
            i=K[w]-1; // previous location
            K[w]=-1; // set this so we know we've visited it
        }

        for(;++j<L;) // print out result
            C.Write(j%2<1?K[j]<0?j==s?'S':j==e?'X':'.':'#':S[j]); // if K < 0, we visit it, otherwise we don't
    }
}
```